# What is the best way to combine these two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting mysql errors when I try to write joins or unions combining these two queries.  field1A and field1B are the conditions I am trying to count.

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `table1` c1 
    LEFT JOIN `table2` j1 ON (j1.`field1A` = '1') 
WHERE (c1.`field2` = 'Yes' AND c1.`field` is null)")
```

and

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM `table1` c1 
    LEFT JOIN `table2` j1 ON (j1.`field1B` = '1') 
WHERE (c1.`field2` = 'Yes' AND c1.`field` is null)")
```

I am sure there is a more elegant way than running both queries and adding the totals together.

Comment: If you are using a left join, shouldn't you get the same count for each query?

Comment: How does *table1* and *table2* relate? As now queries are simply filtered cross joins.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from single select as follows.

```
SELECT count(*) 
   FROM `table1` c1 
        LEFT JOIN `table2` j1 ON (j1.`field1A` = '1')  AND (j1.`field1B` = '1')
    WHERE (c1.`field2` = 'Yes' AND c1.`field` is null)
```

Comment: If "combine" means that the sum of the numbers from the query should match the sum from this, then this does not "combine" the results.  In particular, the count is off for `j1` rows where both conditions are true.